# One post out of more than twenty shows odd picture (from post) in the header

Tags: posts, header-image

(WP 3.5.1)

My blog has a header picture showing its name. But for some reason exactly one post shows a picture in the header which is actually used within the post itself.

http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/frequency-of-character-combinations/

I don't even know how I would acomplish such feat if I wanted - given that the header code as far as I know is included from header.php and hence keeps the same references in every single post...

How do I find out what the reason is, so I can change the header image back to the right one !?

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Is this an unmodified twentyeleven theme? functions.php right out of the box?

Comment: does that post have a featured image? with the dimensions larger than the header dimensions?

Comment: I really like this header image. :) Is there any function in your theme that sets the first post image as featured image?

Comment: @vancoder: yes, 20-11 out of the box

Comment: @Michael: that was it! chose a small featured image and the header is back to normal. If you make an answer out of it, I can confirm it.

Comment: @toscho: the featured image is chosen manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Twenty Eleven, any featured image in a post or static page, with image dimensions larger than the size of the header image - 1000px width in the unedited theme - will automatically get used for the header image.